# error_messages for ManyToManyField in ModelForm

Tags: django, forms

I have model with ManyToManyField field. I also have ModelForm that uses this model.

How to define error_messages for such field?

Example:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta(ContentForm.Meta):
        model = Article
```

I want to override 'required' error message for categories field in ArticleForm model.

I was Googling about this problem but all solutions not work either they are not form ModelForm or for ManyToManyField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do your own validation for this field. In model set for m2m field blank=True, and in form implement clean_categories method. If field categories is not valid, raise exception with your content.

In model:

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
```

In form:

```
def clean_categories(self):
    if not self.cleaned_data.get('categories'):
        raise forms.ValidationError('My custom message')
    return self.cleaned_data['categories']
```

Comment: It's clean, explicit and short solution, so I accept it. Still, solution when you really override error message would be appreciated even more (it would be more DRY). Thx for help.

Comment: Maybe to by more DRY (if you need change error message in more than one form), the good idea could be subclassing forms.ModelForm. Subclass will change message, and your forms would use that subclass. I don't know is it possible, I have to check it. Thanks for acceptance.